# Is apparent competition a suitable term in situations where one species is not negatively affected?

Tags: ecology, terminology

When two prey (or resource) species share a common predator (consumer), they can be in apparent competition. An increase in one prey species can increase the common predator density, which negatively influences the other prey species.

A textbook (Molles, Seventh edition, ISBN-10: 0077837282) gives an example of apparent competition that confuses me. It gives another definition "one species facilitating populations of a predator or herbivore of the second species." Thus, one of the species does not have to be consumed by the predator/herbivore.

The specific example is that there are two plant species. Species A becomes the habitat for the herbivore (but is not consumed by the herbivore). Species B is consumed by the herbivore. Therefore, an increase in species A will increase the herbivore density and has negative effects on species B. I thought that to form an apparent competition relationship, it has to be mutually negative relationship (-,-).  In this example, there is no mutually negative relationship. Furthermore, the plants do not share the common herbivore.

This is simply a definition question. Different sources have variable definitions, but is the example really considered an apparent competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Competition-like interactions where only one species suffers ([0,-]) are usually labelled [amensalism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_interaction), so a suitable term for the situation you describe should be "*apparent amensalism*". I hadn't actually seen this term in use from before, but a quick Google search reveals that is in fact used. One example is in [Jaworski et al. (2015)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10340-015-0698-3):

> Indirect interactions mediated by shared natural enemies are known as apparent competition, if negative interactions are reciprocal, or **apparent amensalism**, if one prey suffers from the presence of the other prey (Holt 1977; Holt and Lawton 1994).